# How to click this dialog with Detox? Obvious solution but I still can't tap it

Tags: react-native, automated-tests, detox

[image]

I have come across this issue and research all related forums

[Issues No.9](https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/9)

[How to confirm alert message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47522081/detox-ios-simulator-how-to-confirm-alert-message)

[Can't accept location permission from system alert pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55820649/react-native-detox-cant-accept-location-permission-from-system-alert-pop-up)

[How to tap on allow button on permission pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56351127/how-to-tap-on-allow-button-on-permission-pop-up)

yet nothing works.

Any other solution? Suggestion?
In those links, people didn't seem to have an obvious solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detox uses applesimutils to set permissions. This is battle tested in production at Wix and in Detox CI. Check out the docs and test project for examples.

Comment: Have you test it with `react-native-onesignal` installed?

Comment: We don’t test external packages normally. But the way applesimutils works is by modifying the simulator itself.

Answer (score 4):

It's my solution!

```
await device.launchApp({ 
    permissions: { userTracking: 'YES', location: 'always', notifications: 'YES', reminders: 'YES', }, 
});
```

Comment: Works and save me a lot of time ! Thanks !